# How to use datasummary_skim() on groups in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, modelsummary

I like to have the awesome statistics of `datasummary_skim()` from `modelsummary` package by groups.

```
library(modelsummary)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% datasummary_skim()
```

[image]

How can I have a grouped data summary?

```
mtcars %>% group_by(vs) %>% datasummary_skim()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution including group titles and plotting all tables on a scrollable panel:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  summarize(summary = datasummary_skim(data, title = vs)) %>% 
  pull(summary)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

One option is to split the dataframe by groups, and then use `map()` to apply `datasummary_skim()` to each child dataframe:

```
mtcars |>
  group_split(cyl) |>
  map(datasummary_skim)
```

Output:

[image: table 1 other tables follow]

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI, I posted a simpler option with the latest `modelsummary`. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: neat answer, but I don't see why you needed to ping everyone about your answer

Comment: @Vincent "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post." https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.0.0 of `modelsummary` includes a `by` argument in the `datasummary_skim()` function. You can wait until the new version reaches CRAN, or install the development version from Github:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("vincentarelbundock/tinytable")
install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

```
library(modelsummary)
x <- mtcars[, c("hp", "mpg", "gear")]

datasummary_skim(x, by = "gear")
```

[image]